# Assigning a vector to a matrix cell

Tags: image, matlab, vector, matrix

Say for example that I have the following matrix representing some image:

```
I=[1 2; 5 7; 7 5];
```

Getting the vector for the above matrix, we can do the following:

```
I_vector=I(:);
```

At the same time, say that we have the following vector that was retrieved after applying some operations on `I`

```
f=[5 65 65; 65 67 98; 7 7 9; 87 34 86; 65 87 87; 86 23 07; 76 89 13];
```

Say that for each element in `I`, I want to assign a vector value. So, instead of having `I(1)=1`, I want it to be `I(1)=[5 65 65]`. So, when calling `I(1)`, we get the latter result.

Is that possible in `matlab`?

Thanks.

Comment: you can assign a row of a matrix like this: `f(1,:) = [5 65 65]`. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

If the vectors you want to place inside `I` are all of the **same length**, then store it as a **matrix** and call by row:

```
I(1,:)
```

If the the vectors are **not of the same length**, then store it in a **cell array** and access the content of each cell with `{ }`:

```
I = {1:10, 1:20}
I{2}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you kindly just clarify me the first solution. When you say the vectors are all of the same length, you mean here the features?

Comment: Yes, I know how to access the rows. But, the question is how to assign them to `I`? Thanks

Comment: You can convert to cell with `I = num2cell(f,2)`, and then use `I{1}`. the question is why would you want to do that when everything is stored conveniently in a matrix?

Comment: @ Oleg Komarov. The case is that I want to represent each pixel in terms of its feature vectors. Does that makes sense?

Comment: So, does my previous comment fits your needs, and if not elaborate please.